# Drawbacks to using Options -Indexes

Tags: htaccess, directory

I was wondering if there were any drawbacks to using Options -Indexes in my WordPress htaccess file to block access to directories such as uploads, etc.

Wpbeginner has a post on it [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/disable-directory-browsing-wordpress/)

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Options -Indexes` doesn't "block access", it prevents directory listings being auto-generated when there is no `DirectoryIndex` document in that directory. Files in that directory can still be accessed and indexed if they are discovered by some other means.

Comment: I've also added the directory to my robots.txt file to block robots. I know the files are still accessible but at least they are not indexed. Do you have any recommendation to further secure these directories?

Comment: I think `robots.txt` is sufficient, providing the files are not sensitive (which would require some kind of authentication). Another alternative (instead of `robots.txt`) to prevent _indexing_ would be to send the `X-Robots-Tag: noindex` HTTP response header in response to such requests. Since `robots.txt` prevents _crawling_, it doesn't necessarily prevent _indexing_, if the document gets publicly linked to. However, it may be preferable to prevent unnecessary crawling in this instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some legitimate use cases for enabling `Indexes` but they're probably not applicable to most sites (especially WordPress sites).

For example `Indexes` are helpful on file storage mirrors where you want to provide readonly access to a subset of folders & files without having to build your own UI.

As a best practice, yes, disable them globally using `Options -Indexes`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm currently using the Job Manger plugin which allows users to upload their resumes to our site. The file that they upload goes into the public uploads directory. Currently those files are accessible while also being indexed.